# Optimize stream read-write operation in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, optimization, stream, puppeteer

I am using a npm package **puppeteer-stream** to get the **stream** of the **page**. The stream contains the **audio-video** of the **page** and after capturing the stream I pipe the stream into a file. Later when I have recorded everything I require I just simply close my file, upload it to **aws s3** and destroy the stream.

Here is my code:

```
        stream = await getStream(page, { audio: true, video: true, bitsPerSecond: 60 });
        stream.pipe(file);
```

After I have recorded everything:

```
        file?.close();
        await stream?.destroy(); 
        const fileName = 'filename', fileDir = 'filedir';
        const awsObjectInfo = await awsService.uploadFileToS3(file, fileName, fileDir);
```

The **duration** of the **recording** is usually more than **1 hour**.

Initially this approach was working fine but its not very optimized. On the server side I am using a  **aws ec2 type t2.medium Instance** but during this process the **cpu utilization** goes very **high (ex: 95%)** and **video-audio** becomes very **choppy**.

How can I optimize this file writing operation so It consumes less cpu power, can someone please suggest some methods to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the stream directly to s3 upload, instead of write it in your server.

It will look like this:

```
stream = await getStream(page, { audio: true, video: true, bitsPerSecond: 60 });
s3.upload({ Body: stream }, (err, data) => { /*..some code*/ });
```

When the stream is finished writing, s3 upload callback will be called.

This can save some cpu. Hope that's help.